# Using DSolve solution as function

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding this Mathematica syntax.

if I do

`y[x] /. DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]`

I'd expect that I now have a function $y(x) = e^x$, such that when I write

`y[0]` or even `N[y[0]]` that I should get `1`, but Mathematica won't evaluate it and instead writes `y[0]`

Why? And how can I create a *real* mathematica function `y[x] = e^x` from the `DSolve` Function

Comment: You can do this `% /. x -> 0`

Comment: For a function, `y[x_] = Flatten[%]` and then try `y[0]`.

Comment: ok I'll give that a try.

Comment: `y /. DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, x]`?

Comment: Duplicate Confirmed, sorry, didn't come across that post for some reason, even though this obvious title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 In[1]:= y1[x_] = 
 y[x] /. First[DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]]

Out[1]= E^x

In[2]:= y1[0]

Out[2]= 1
```

Comment: No its not different. I finished typing it in and then saw your comment :) I can remove it if you want.

Comment: This works. I couldn't get @zhk 's comment to work, however I guess that's just due to my incompetence. I think however that Lotus was first, just took more time to write the answer down, so he gets the accepted answer.